# PHP login forms not working

Tags: php, sql

I have been making/learning some PHP, and I successfully made a login form. When I have tried to replicate this, it doesn't work at all.

--MY HTML--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="login.php">
    <input type="text" name="usrname" placeholder=" Username">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="password" name="passwd" placeholder=" Password">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="password" name="pin" placeholder=" PIN #">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

--LOGIN.PHP--

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('php/db.php');
    $usrname = $_POST['usrname'];
    $passwd = $_POST['passwd'];
    $pin = $_POST['pin'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usrname = 'usrname'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $usrnameFromDB = $row['usrname'];
    $passwdFromDB = $row['passwd'];
    $pinFromDB = $row['pin'];

    if($usrnameFromDB == $usrname && $passwdFromDB == $passwd && $pinFromDB == $pin) {
        echo "Correct";
    } else {
        echo "noooooo"; 
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>trhhytrh</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

P.S. When comparing the codes, there is no major difference apart from the names. Also, the code provided is the one that isn't working. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Comment: When i am making proper sites, I use mysqli, but this site is for my kids so they can have a bank so if they do chores I will pay them. I am not concerned about security but thanks anyway.

Comment: `'usrname'` guess what you missed here?

Comment: I intentionally left the 'e' out if thats what you mean.

Comment: Thanks so much! I missed the $ :)

Comment: no. `WHERE usrname = 'usrname'";` => `WHERE usrname = '$usrname'";` - You're presently looking for the string literal of "usrname" in your db rather than the POST array's variable.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh I see you saw what I meant ;-) you're welcome.

Comment: @Skye It is not a security aspect. `mysql_*` API will be removed in the next php version

Comment: @Jens Ahh I understand now, I always thought it was to prevent mysql injection. Learn something new everyday. :)

Comment: @Skye Jens' comment was a good one, however using mysqli or PDO on its own and without a prepared statement, does not safeguard against an SQL injection.

Comment: I am reading the references you gave me in your answer as we speak and I believe I know how to prevent mysql injection. My uni never taught me how to prevent mysql injection. Thankyou for the help :)

Comment: *You're welcome*. You might even want to read up on XSS injection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in comments:

`WHERE usrname = 'usrname'";` it should read as `WHERE usrname = '$usrname'";`

You're presently looking/querying for the string literal of "usrname" in your database, rather than the POST array's variable.

Heed the warnings about SQL injection. You should use a prepared statement and a safe password hashing function when your site does go live, such as `password_hash()`.

You should not put that much trust in people.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Will mark this as the answer when it lets me, I will also be planning on using  md5 with a random 6 varchar salt. Also, unsure if it helps but I will also be using 'mysqli_real_escape_string' when my site goes live. Thankyou for the help kind sir!

Comment: @Skye You're welcome. I suggest you not use MD5 as it is no longer considered safe to use as a password storage method. Read the following http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure it outlines the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change this in html

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
```

Then in php

```
<?php
session_start();
include('php/db.php');
if(isset $_POST['submit']){
$usrname = $_POST['usrname'];
$passwd = $_POST['passwd'];
$pin = $_POST['pin'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usrname = '$usrname'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$usrnameFromDB = $row['usrname'];
$passwdFromDB = $row['passwd'];
$pinFromDB = $row['pin'];

if($usrnameFromDB == $usrname && $passwdFromDB == $passwd && $pinFromDB == $pin) {
    echo "Correct";
} else {
    echo "noooooo"; 
}
}//End of if

else
{
echo "Form is not submitted";
}
?>
```

You have not submitted the form. PS you have commited a mistake in your query. You were not using variable there

Comment: I never knew the 'isset($_POST['submit'])' was a thing. I will be using this in all of my future sites, Thanks!

Comment: I think its better practice to wrap all of your form elements in single condition.